# Codeigniter REST. How to properly protect against csrf

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, csrf

I am using the REST server by Phil Sturgeon and I was wondering how I can do CSRF Protection properly? Currently I am using this method:

```
if(stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'API')!=""){
    $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
}else{
    $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;}
```

However, I have read that this is not the proper way to protect against csrf attacks. I have tried to extend MY_Security but I am unsure of what I need to do after I extend the class. This is the extended class

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Security extends  CI_Security {


    public function csrf_verify()
    {

        // If it's not a POST request we will set the CSRF cookie
        if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) !== 'POST')
        {
            return $this->csrf_set_cookie();
        }

                /**
                 *  mine implementation for application/json
                 */
                $reqHeaders = getallheaders();
                $content_type = $reqHeaders["Content-Type"];

                #it's a json request?
                if(preg_match("/(application\/json)/i",$content_type))
                {
                    #the check the cookie from request
                    $reqCookies = explode("; ",$reqHeaders["Cookie"]);
                    foreach($reqCookies as $c)
                    {
                        if(preg_match("/(".$this->_csrf_cookie_name."\=)/", $c))
                        {
                          $c = explode("=",$c);

                          if($_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name] == $c[1])
                          {
                             return $this; 
                          }
                        }
                    }

                }
                //< end

        // Check if URI has been whitelisted from CSRF checks
        if ($exclude_uris = config_item('csrf_exclude_uris'))
        {
            $uri = load_class('URI', 'core');
            foreach ($exclude_uris as $excluded)
            {
                if (preg_match('#^'.$excluded.'$#i'.(UTF8_ENABLED ? 'u' : ''), $uri->uri_string()))
                {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }

        // Do the tokens exist in both the _POST and _COOKIE arrays?
        if ( ! isset($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name], $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name])
            OR $_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name] !== $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name]) // Do the tokens match?
        {
            $this->csrf_show_error();
        }

        // We kill this since we're done and we don't want to polute the _POST array
        unset($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name]);

        // Regenerate on every submission?
        if (config_item('csrf_regenerate'))
        {
            // Nothing should last forever
            unset($_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name]);
            $this->_csrf_hash = NULL;
        }

        $this->_csrf_set_hash();
        $this->csrf_set_cookie();

        log_message('info', 'CSRF token verified');
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Do I need to set headers for each json POST or get request? This is an example of what I send to my REST backend

```
public function user_create_activity($activity){
        $this->curl->create(UserCreateActivity);
        $this->curl->http_login(REST_KEY_ID,REST_KEY_PASSWORD);
        $this->curl->post(array(
            'activity' => $activity,
        ));
        return json_decode($this->curl->execute(),true);
    }
```

I am quite unsure if I am on the right path. Hopefully someone can guide me.

Thank you.

Comment: CodeIgniter's CSRF protection is a cookie based solution. You can certainly use cookies with curl, but you would have to do an initial authentication type request to get a cookie. In general, using CodeIgniter's CSRF protection for every request is a bad idea. If you'll take a moment to research what CSRF really is, then you'd see why you probably don't need it for every request to your website, and why your thoughts of needing it for your REST API are probably not valid concerns.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your advice. May I know how would you recommend I secure a REST backend?

Comment: First of all, force HTTPS. Next, you have a regular website where users sign up and have an account. In that account they obtain their own unique authorization key and password for their API usage. This is how many APIs work, and it doesn't matter if they are REST or not. Authorization keys and passwords for the API should be complex (minimum 24 chars or so).